# How can I sync my home folder "both ways" using rsync

Tags: sync, home-directory, rsync

I would like to sync my home folder using a server with ssh, is it possible to do it with rsync?
I need to be able to sync it between a few computers.

Thanks for your help

Comment: A webserver can't really sync anything, it serves webpages. An rsync server daemon only acts as a one end of an rsync command. If you want your home directory to be shared across multiple machines you would probably do best to host it on one machine and have the others NFS mount it from the host. If you want multiple copies, all kept in sync with each other, you'll need to better explain your needs.

Comment: I meant a dedicated server with ssh access.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Unison](http://packages.ubuntu.com/unison) is the bidirectional equivalent of rsync. Normally it just runs with no fuss, copying from whichever side has changed to the other side. If there's a conflict, i.e. you've changed the file on both sides, it tells you and asks you what to do.

To synchronize between more than two machines, use a star pattern where there is a center machine and any number of satellite machines: run unison between each satellite machine and the center machine. In your setup, the server would be the center machine.

Comment: I use Unison, it's great.